# Should allow upload file in the same page or a new page?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, cards

I am building a web site  where students have to do their homework online.

I have a page that shows a list of cards , every card represent a homework.
On every homework the students have to upload files.

I am thinking on two options :

1) Display  a   list of cards whith a short description and when the user click it , open   a new page showing the full homework description,some details  and allow the student upload their file.

2)  Display  a   list of cards whith a short description and when the user click it  , expand the card showing the the full homework description, some details and allow the student upload their file.

The homework description could be very large on some cases.

*English isn’t my first language, so please excuse any mistakes*

Comment: Welcome to UX.SE! Good first question (and do not worry about your English. It is very good!).

Answer (score 1):

As a former student, I would much prefer that the homework assignment details would **open in a new page**.

The benefits of opening in its own page are numerous:

- It helps the student focus on one homework assignment at a time.

  The student doesn't need to be concerned with other assignments while working on one. It is likely that the student will complete one assignment at a time, so there isn't much need to be able to quickly switch focus between multiple assignments, like expanding the card would allow them to do.
- It reduces the chance that a student will upload a document to the wrong assignment, as they are likely to already be looking at the detailed view while completing the assignment.
- It (hopefully) would provide a static URL that will always direct back to the same assignment.

  This means that if a student wants to bookmark a particular assignment to quickly come back to it, they may do so. `homeworkserverexample.com/assignments/{homework assignment ID}` is more useful than `homeworkserverexample.com/assignments` and having to scroll or filter items to find a particular one.